# Liferay behind haproxy, users cannot login

Tags: cookies, https, liferay, haproxy

We are running liferay behind haproxy.

While we were running liferay independently we were able to login without problems. However after introduction haproxy with ssl termination users experienced a weird behaviour. After restart of liferay no user is able login and there are no error messages in the log files.

Once user try to login, login form is send with filled data to the server and user is redirected back to welcome page and

- No error in logs.
- Cookies seems to be properly set.

Moreover we find out that once we clear the browser cache or open page in private mode users are able to login.

We tried also to clear only the browser cookies, but it doesn't help.

Can you please advice why this happens or explain such a behaviour?

Thanks.

haproxy config

```
frontend  lb-fe-https-env
    bind 10.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/dev.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

    acl host_portal_dev hdr(host) -i www-dev.dev1.sk
    acl host_content_dev hdr(host) -i content-dev.dev1.sk

    use_backend be_content_dev if host_content_dev
    use_backend be_portal_dev if host_portal_dev

backend be_portal_dev
        redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
        balance roundrobin
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix indirect nocache
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        server dev1 dev1.portal.com:80 check cookie dev1
```

liferay portal-ext.properties

```
web.server.protocol=https
```

Comment: IMHO this should rather be migrated to serverfault.com - it's not programming-related at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, than sorry for post. Anyway if somebody will face similar issue, it was caused by haproxy configuration. Once we disabled this line it works fine.

```
cookie JSESSIONID prefix indirect nocache
```